# Variadic function that returns the number of arguments that are passed to it

Tags: c++, c++11

I tried to implement a function that returns the number of arguments that are passed to it. Here's the code :

```
int SIZE(int n, ...){

va_list ARGS;
va_start (ARGS, n);
int length(0);

void* current_arg;
do{
    current_arg=va_arg(ARGS, void*);
    length++;
}while( current_arg != nullptr);

va_end(ARGS);
return length;

}
```

I had done some research prior to this, so I kinda knew it wan't going to work. And indeed it didn't : when I passed two arguments to it, it returned 12 !
I'd still like to understand why it didn't work. I see two options :

- There's a problem in the way I designed the algorithm that makes it malfunction.
- A function takes many more arguments that the ones that are explicitly given to it.

I haven't been programming for very long, so I like experimenting with this kind of stuff.
Could you help me figure out what is wrong with my function please ?
Thanks

Comment: Since you're using C++ 11, you should use variadic templates instead.

Comment: Unless you pass pointers, the actual size of the arguments might differ from `sizeof(void*)`. Furthermore, non-pointer values can't be equal to `nullptr`.

Comment: Vararg lists do not carry their size nor the type of their contents. You have to manage that yourself. That's why they have been replaced by variadic templates, which do all of that and much more.

Comment: Related to Carl's comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...

Comment: do you want to know how to fix it, or why the code you wrote produces wrong output?

Comment: Both, I guess. Thanks everyone for the answers so far :)

Answer (score 6):

Since you tagged C++11 you should consider [parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) making your function:

```
template<typename... T>
constexpr unsigned numberOfArguments(const T&... args)
{
    return sizeof...(T);
}
```

As seen in the comments on the main post, the `sizeof...()` operator will return the size of the template parameter pack in this case.